# WPF design UserControl / DataTemplate problem

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have a WPF UserControl representing a Person with many fields.
Some Persons can be a company. In this case I'd like to use another template with other fields. The code behind is the same, that's why I want it as a 1 control only with 2 templates.

What I'd like to do is to be able to define these 2 templates **with** the VS designer support so I could easily change them.

The problem ist that some elements have **EventHandlers** attached (Click...) and I can't image how I could resolve that when **using DataTemplate**. (Perhaps supposing the bubble events register the EventHandler on one of the parents ? and then look for the original source name ?)
Or should I use 2 **UserControls** and then somehow merge them in my main UserControl ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx) to your usercontrol class and have the buttons execute the commands. This is a much used pattern in [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). See http://codingcontext.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/commandbindings-in-mvvm/ or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx